# How to write the symbol in Baby Rudin for the set of bounded continuous functions on metric space X

Tags: symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a math symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol)

I just could not find the command to write the symbol in Baby Rudin (*Principles of Mathematical Analysis*) for the set of bounded continuous functions on metric space *X*, for example on page 150 of its 1976 edition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean the curly C? I think you want

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathscr{C}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Qiang - no problem. Incidentally, the best place to find symbols is in [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive).

Comment: @Qiang, @Ian: I think that nowadays, I'd say that [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is the best place to find symbols (but of course, it's built on top of the Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List).